# How to configure krakend.json to forward parameterized url?

Tags: go, api-gateway

Basically I just want to forward this request:

> http://somehost:4321/api/v1/{uid}/profile

into this:

> http://123.45.67.89:4321/api/{uid}/profile

I've done this in krakend.json:

```
{
      "version": 2,
      "timeout": "3000ms",
      "cache_ttl": "300s",
      "name": "myapi",
      "output_encoding": "json",
      "port": 4321,
      "endpoints": [
          {
              "endpoint": "/api/v1/{uid}/profile",
              "method": "GET",
              "headers_to_pass": [ "*" ],
              "querystring_params": [ "*" ],
              "output_encoding": "no-op",
              "concurrent_calls": 1,
              "backend": [
                  {
                      "url_pattern": "/api/{uid}/profile",
                      "encoding": "no-op",
                      "host": [
                          "http://123.45.67.89:4321"
                      ]
                  }
              ]
          }
      ]
}
```

But ends up with error:

> panic: wildcard route ':uid' conflicts with existing children in path '/api/v1/:uid/profile'

Any clue?

Answer (score 1):

Its turn out that I've declared same pattern as endpoint:

```
{
      "version": 2,
      "timeout": "3000ms",
      "cache_ttl": "300s",
      "name": "myapi",
      "output_encoding": "json",
      "port": 4321,
      "endpoints": [
          {
              "endpoint": "/api/v1/me/profile",
              "method": "GET",
              "headers_to_pass": [ "*" ],
              "output_encoding": "no-op",
              "concurrent_calls": 1,
              "backend": [
                  {
                      "url_pattern": "/api/me/profile",
                      "encoding": "no-op",
                      "host": [
                          "http://123.45.67.89:4321"
                      ]
                 }
             ]
          },
          {
              "endpoint": "/api/v1/{uid}/profile",
              "method": "GET",
              "headers_to_pass": [ "*" ],
              "querystring_params": [ "*" ],
              "output_encoding": "no-op",
              "concurrent_calls": 1,
              "backend": [
                  {
                      "url_pattern": "/api/{uid}/profile",
                      "encoding": "no-op",
                      "host": [
                          "http://123.45.67.89:4321"
                      ]
                  }
              ]
          }
      ]
}
```

After changed into this, it works well:

```
{
      "version": 2,
      "timeout": "3000ms",
      "cache_ttl": "300s",
      "name": "myapi",
      "output_encoding": "json",
      "port": 4321,
      "endpoints": [
          {
              "endpoint": "/api/v1/me/profile",
              "method": "GET",
              "headers_to_pass": [ "*" ],
              "output_encoding": "no-op",
              "concurrent_calls": 1,
              "backend": [
                  {
                      "url_pattern": "/api/me/profile",
                      "encoding": "no-op",
                      "host": [
                          "http://123.45.67.89:4321"
                      ]
                 }
             ]
          },
          {
              "endpoint": "/api/v1/user/{uid}/profile",
              "method": "GET",
              "headers_to_pass": [ "*" ],
              "querystring_params": [ "*" ],
              "output_encoding": "no-op",
              "concurrent_calls": 1,
              "backend": [
                  {
                      "url_pattern": "/api/user/{uid}/profile",
                      "encoding": "no-op",
                      "host": [
                          "http://123.45.67.89:4321"
                      ]
                  }
              ]
          }
      ]
}
```

Regards.